# Java boolean returning true when declared false

Tags: java, boolean, bukkit

I am currently making a plugin from the 1.8 Bukkit API. This question however, has to do with booleans. From the beginning of my class file, I have this declaration of a boolean

```
public static boolean lockchat = false;
```

Then I have another boolean in the class file that is used for Bukkit commands:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender s, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
```

This boolean returns true at the end, which I think is making the `lockchat` boolean return true also. If I return false, I am pretty sure that the command code will not return to the user.

My problem is that in this part of my code:

```
if(lockchat == true)
{
    s.sendMessage("unlocked.")
    lockchat = false;
}
else
{
    s.sendMessage("locked.");
    lockchat = true;
}
```

The declaration at the beginning does not seem to matter here, because this always sends me the message unlocked.

I have *tried* to put the declaration inside of the second boolean, but it throws me errors and warnings.

Since the second boolean is returning true, I think that the `lockchat` boolean is returning too. If I would change it to return false, `lockchat` would probably return false also, resulting in another problem.

I want to find a way to have the boolean declaration stay false, while having it changed to true/false inside of the second boolean, as shown. How would I do this?

NOTE: This variable is not used anywhere else in my code.

EDIT: I don't think this will make a difference, but I am testing for the label string to be `"lockchat"`, the same as the boolean name. This probably wouldn't change anything, but just giving more information.

FULL CLASS FILE CODE:

```
package dev.td6.duocraft.commands;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;

import dev.td6.duocraft.main.Duocraft;

public class DCCommandLockChat implements CommandExecutor, Listener
{

    Duocraft plugin;

    public DCCommandLockChat(Duocraft instance)
    {
        plugin = instance;
    }

    public String colorize(String msg)
    {
        String coloredMsg = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++)
        {
            if(msg.charAt(i) == '&')
                coloredMsg += '§';
            else
                coloredMsg += msg.charAt(i);
        }
        return coloredMsg;
    }

    public static boolean lockchat = false;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender s, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
    {

        if(s instanceof Player)
        {
            Player p = (Player) s;

            if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("lockchat"))
            {
                if(p.hasPermission("duocraft.lockchat"))
                {
                    if(args.length >= 1)
                    {
                        if(args.length >= 2)
                        {
                            s.sendMessage("Too many arguments. </lockchat [time]>");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(lockchat == true)
                            {
                                int time = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                                s.sendMessage("locked");
                                lockchat = true;
                                plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("unlocked.");
                                        lockchat = false;
                                        plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTasks(plugin);
                                    }
                                }
                                    , time*20, time*20);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int time = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                                s.sendMessage("locked.");
                                lockchat = true;
                                plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("unlocked.");
                                        lockchat = false;
                                        plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTasks(plugin);
                                    }
                                }
                                    , time*20, time*20);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(lockchat == true)
                        {
                            s.sendMessage("unlocked");
                            lockchat = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            s.sendMessage("unlocked");
                            lockchat = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    p.sendMessage("no access");
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("lockchat"))
            {
                if(args.length >= 1)
                {
                    if(args.length >= 2)
                    {
                        s.sendMessage("Too many args. </lockchat [time]>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(lockchat == true)
                        {
                            int time = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                            s.sendMessage("locked.");
                            lockchat = true;
                            plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("unlocked.");
                                    lockchat = false;
                                    plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTasks(plugin);
                                }
                            }
                                , time*20, time*20);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int time = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                            s.sendMessage("locked");
                            lockchat = true;
                            plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("unlocked");
                                    lockchat = false;
                                    plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTasks(plugin);
                                }
                            }
                                , time*20, time*20);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(lockchat == true)
                    {
                        s.sendMessage("unlocked");
                        lockchat = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s.sendMessage("unlocked");
                        lockchat = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void chatLocked(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e)
    {
        if(lockchat==false)return;
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        if(p.hasPermission("duocraft.lockchat.bypass"))return;

        p.sendMessage("chat is locked.");
        e.setCancelled(true);

    }

}
```

EDIT: Also `public static boolean lockchat = false;` Is not being modified in any way by any other class files.

EDIT: I am using Java 7 for this.

Comment: is the `lockchat` variable used *anywhere* else in your code?

Comment: Are you declaring another `lockchat` variable in this scope?

Comment: Is the lockchat variable used in any method? Does this method have a field with an out variable (which modifies variables)?

Comment: No, except I have another if/else statement checking if it is true or false, however this if/else statement is not ran before the one I put above. I do not change this variable anywhere else in my code.

Comment: please post the complete code. as`lockchat`  is declared as `public static` there is scope for changing it from outside of the class.

Comment: *Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*. At this point, we are just guessing what is going on because you haven't provided a full example.

Comment: @Shirish posted entire class file. EDIT: This boolean is currently not being changed by any other class file.

Comment: Just so you know, you don't "have a second boolean in the class file that is used for Bukkit commands" - you have a method which returns a boolean. I am not familiar enough with the Bukkit API to say what value it should return, however it will have no effect on the value of the `lockchat` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so you know, in your full source you use the following code:

```
if(lockchat == true)
{
    s.sendMessage("unlocked");
    lockchat = false;
}
else
{
    s.sendMessage("unlocked");
    lockchat = true;
}
```

more specifically, you are sending "unlocked" no matter which path the code follows.

Edit: I reformatted your code to reduce some of the duplication. This version fails fast if the CommandSender is a player without permission or the label is not "lockchat". I inferred that the intention is that executing "/lockchat" without an argument should toggle locking immediately, while executing it with an argument should make it toggle for the specified number of seconds and then toggle back. The code below should do this (at least as far as ensuring `lockchat` always has the intended value, but I haven't tested it.

Also, I don't know if the Runnable will be called on a different thread, but if it is you should synchronize all accesses to the shared lockchat variable. At the very least, making it `volatile` (as I do below) may prevent some confusion amongst the threads as to its actual value.

```
public static volatile boolean  lockchat    = false;

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender s, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    // If this is not the 'lockchat' command, then fail fast
    if (!label.equalsIgnoreCase("lockchat")) return true;

    // If s is a Player then check the player has permission and fail fast
    // if not.
    if (s instanceof Player) {
        Player p = (Player) s;
        if (!p.hasPermission("duocraft.lockchat")) {
            p.sendMessage("no access");
            return true;
        }
    }

    switch (args.length) {
    case 0:
        lockchat = !lockchat;
        s.sendMessage(lockchatStatus());
        break;
    case 1:
        int ticks = Integer.valueOf(args[0]) * 20;
        final boolean originalLockChat = lockchat;
        lockchat = !originalLockChat;
        s.sendMessage(lockchatStatus());
        plugin.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleAsyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lockchat = originalLockChat;
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(lockchatStatus() + ".");
                plugin.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTasks(plugin);
            }
        }, ticks, ticks);
        break;
    default:
        s.sendMessage("Too many arguments. </lockchat [time]>");
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

private String lockchatStatus() {
    return lockchat ? "locked" : "unlocked";
}
```

Comment: That's a nice catch, I never noticed that. Now when I test it, it does now switch between the messages. However, now it created a new problem that wasn't there before. It doesn't block the player from sending messages, which it is supposed to do, shown from the even at the end of the code.

Comment: What exactly does `volatile ` do to the boolean?

Comment: It tells the compiler that the variable in question may have its value changed at any time by different threads. Normally the compiler can assume otherwise, and may try to speed code up by giving a copy of the variable to each thread. If the thread writes a new value to the variable, it doesn't change any copy another thread may have. If the compiler is told that the variable is volatile it doesn't make any copies, forcing each thread to make (slower) accesses to the original variable.

Comment: This would matter in your code specifically if your onCommand() method was being called by Bukkit on a different thread to your chatLocked() method - the first one changes the value of the lockchat variable and the second one reads the current value. Because the chatLocked() method doesn't write to the variable the compiler might have taken a local copy for that thread.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Julian's answer, your code is returning unlocked no matter what the value :

```
 if(lockchat == true)
                    {
                        s.sendMessage("unlocked");
                        lockchat = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s.sendMessage("unlocked");
                        lockchat = true;
                    }
```

As per your comment regarding as to why it is not blocking the chat, are you sure you registered your listener? To register your listener, put this line in your onEnable() method in your Main class :

```
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new DCCommandLockChat(), this);
```

Where DCCommandLockChat() is your Listener class and 'this' is your class that extends JavaPlugin.

What this basically does is register your listener for your plugin because otherwise, the server wouldn't pass any events to your listener and so your listener wouldn't know what would be happening on the server.

Also, as for the method itself returning true or false, both values will still run the command. As far as I know, the only time the return value of the onCommand method matters is when you're using aliases in your plugin.yml. If the method returns false, then the server will send the player a message with the aliases. Aside from that, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I already did register it, I was thinking it was because of permissions, but I was neither op, nor did I have the permission duocraft.lockchat.bypass

Answer (score 0):

You should give the boolean (lockchat) the value you want in the constructor of your class.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? my current constructor is defining an instance from my main class. Can you also explain exactly how giving this boolean the value in the structure, would change anything than from just declaring it.

Comment: What I mean is something like this :
public DCCommandLockChat(Duocraft instance)
    {
        plugin = instance;
        lockchat = false;
    }

Comment: Constructor or inside class declaration, there's no difference for this code.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> I want to find a way to have the boolean declaration stay false, while having it changed to true/false inside of the second boolean, as shown. How would I do this?

At the beginning of the body of whichever statement you want, make a temporary variable to store `lockChat`'s value.

`boolean lockChatTemp = lockChat;`

Then, use and modify that value within your function. This way, `lockChat` will keep its value throughout.

Also,

`if (lockChat == true)`

can be replaced with

`if (lockChat)` since the statement inside the parentheses evaluates to a `boolean`, and `lockChat` is already a `boolean`.

Comment: I don't get exactly what you mean by _Then, use and modify that value within your function. This way, lockChat will keep its value throughout._ I don't see how making another declaration would make a difference. I tried your way of making a templockchat declaration, and even tried changing regular `lockchat` boolean to private. Either way, they both do nothing different.